# Django 1.1 to Django 1.3

Tags: python, django

I have read the Django book, but for the old version 1.1.

Other than rereading the book for the updated version, what is the quickest way to get up to date with the new and the deprecated features? I know I can look at the changelog, but I was looking for some more detailed resources, maybe some blog posts.

Comment: How is the change log not detailed enough?  It's very detailed.  What more could you be looking for?  Can you provide an example of something in the changelog that's **not** detailed enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is posts explaining in much more detail each feature. [Djangoadvent](http://djangoadvent.com/) did has it for 1.2.

By the time 1.3 came out, many of these people who wrote these posts last time around, got busy with their (new founded) startups (via YC'11)!

You can refer the release notes tho':

[Django 1.3 release notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/)

[Django 1.2 release notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/)

Comment: +1 Was just going to mention django advent, it was great at highlighting the use cases.

Comment: Thank you, it is just what I was looking for. There is no such thing for 1.3, but it is promised on twitter.com/djangoadvent :-)

Answer (score 2):

release notes, avail for each step see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/